# Why is TV size relevant for wall-mounting?

Tags: safety, mounting, television

Looking at specifications of TV wall mounts, in addition to maximum weight they are also rated for maximum size (screen diagonal). Why is that? Assuming the mounting holes match and the TV doesn't exceed the maximum weight, what problems can arise from using a mount with a larger TV than the specs allow?

As an example, I have a tilted wall mount that is rated for up to 30 kg and 32" displays. My current TV is 32", but I'm looking to upgrade to a 50" one. Can I keep using the same wall mount? The new TV weighs 14 kg, so less than half of what the mount can support (the old one is even less, ~10 kg). Or is there something I'm overlooking?

In case it's relevant, the walls are concrete, so I don't need to worry about things like wall stud spacing.

Comment: Ultimately its a way to simplify the shopping process.  The weight the unit will support is a bigger concern.  TVs keep getting lighter, so that is a plus in your favor.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I suspected this was a way for mount manufacturers to provide a rough guideline, but wanted to double-check. You should expand your comment into a full answer.

Answer (score 4):

Two possible issues come to mind:

1. The larger screen will not physically fit in the tv wall mount
2. The leverage of the larger screen can tear out the fixings (`torque = force * distance`).

Comment: "*the larger screen will not physically fit in the tv wall mount*" Can you clarify this? The wall mount attaches to the back of the TV, and as long as the mounting holes line up (I've checked, they do, standard VESA 200x200 mm), it should be fine, right?

Comment: Solar Mike was describing a fatal issue - if your TV doesn't actually fit the mount, then clearly you cannot use the mount.  If it does fit, then his second issue might be a concern.  The spec for the mount you have may have been estimating weight as a function of size for the technology available when it was manufactured, - i.e., back in the day a 32" TV weighed as much as the mount could handle but that's just a guess.  IMO, if the weight's good, then you are OK.

Comment: @mike65535 Ah, I think I understand now. The first issue is not that the TV's own physical dimensions might affect compatibility with the mount, but that a larger TV might use a larger variant of the VESA standard and therefore be incompatible with a mount designed for smaller TVs, right? That makes sense, but my question was specifically about the TV's own dimensions, with the assumption that mounting holes are compatible. As for the second issue, how would I actually estimate the increased leverage and whether it could pose problems?

Comment: Math isn't usually the answer in a situation like this. There are too many unknown variables. If your 32" unit doesn't seem to be stressing the mount, and it doesn't flex substantially when you try twisting it a bit, it'll probably hold the 50" unit well. The key is in the fasteners, and panels seem to get lighter every year anyway.

Comment: I originally thought this was a torque issue too, but I don't see any way that a larger TV could increase the torque. The center of mass of the larger TV will be in the exact same spot as the center of mass of the smaller TV, so the torque length is identical. You can't move the center of mass any further away from the wall than you could for the smaller TV.

Comment: @NuclearWang well, if a kid pulls on one corner... then you get more leverage and the fixing spacings may then be insufficient....

Comment: @NuclearWang not if you velcro a Comcast box to the back of the TV.   Also, nowhere is it written TVs must have a center of gravity at their centerline.

Comment: @SolarMike So is that the type of problem you're referring to in issue 2? That when external force (i.e. beyond the weight of the TV) is applied, with a larger TV it can generate more torque due to the greater distance from the mount?